Different result between notepad++ XML Validation and C# XMLDocument.validate
I'm trying to enforce a uniqueness constraint for a combination of attributes across two elements using an XSD. The constraint works correctly in Notepad++ but not in my C# application.
I've added the following unique statement to my XSD:
<xs:unique name="uniqueEMNameParentID">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//EM"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
    <xs:field xpath=".//Station/@ID"/>
</xs:unique>

And this is an example of my XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PLC Name="PLC">
    <Type>
      <TypeDef ID="1" Name="G05" Description="" />
    </Type>
    <SA ID="01">
      <Station ID="100">
        <EM ID="01" Name="IR01" IsRobot="TRUE">          
        </EM>
      </Station>
    </SA>
    <SA ID="02">
      <Station ID="100">
        <EM ID="02" Name="IR01" IsRobot="TRUE">
        </EM>
        <EM ID="03" Name="IR03" IsRobot="TRUE">      
        </EM>
      </Station>
    </SA>
  </PLC>
</Project>

When using Notepad++ the XSD gives me the correct error: "IR01 is a duplicate key for the unique identity constraint 'uniqueEMNameParentID'." However, when validating the same XML against the XSD in C# using the code below, no error is reported:
 private void ValidateXML()
 {
     XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
     schema.Add("", @"Z:\VMshare\Maarten\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\XML\XSDScheme3.xsd");
     projectXML.Schemas.Add(schema);

     projectXML.Validate((object sender, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs args) =>
     {
         MessageBox.Show(args.Message);
     });
 }

My XML Document does not contain any namespaces, my XSD does not contain a targetnamespace and both attribute and elementformdefault are set to unqualified. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?
Note that my XML has two Station elements with the attribute ID=100. These elements both have a child element EM with the attribute name = IR01. This should not be possible.
Complete XSD:
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Project">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PLC">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Type">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="TypeDef">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID"/>
                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Description"/>
                                                    </xs:extension>
                                                </xs:simpleContent>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="SA" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="Station" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="EM" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                                <xs:element name="Robot">
                                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                                            <xs:element name="Jobs">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                        <xs:element name="Job" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                                                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Description" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Type" use="optional"/>
                                                                                                    </xs:extension>
                                                                                                </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                                                                        </xs:element>
                                                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                            <xs:element name="Areas">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                        <xs:element name="Area" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                                                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Description" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="TargetEM_No" use="optional"/>
                                                                                                    </xs:extension>
                                                                                                </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                                                                        </xs:element>
                                                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                            <xs:element name="Userbits">
                                                                                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                        <xs:element name="Userbit" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                                                                            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                                                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                    <xs:element name="Reference" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                                                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                            <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                                                    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Area" use="optional"/>
                                                                                                                    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Job" use="optional"/>
                                                                                                                </xs:extension>
                                                                                                            </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                    </xs:element>
                                                                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID" use="required"/>
                                                                                                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Description" use="required"/>
                                                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                                                                        </xs:element>
                                                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                            <xs:element name="FZones">
                                                                                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                        <xs:element name="FZone" minOccurs="0">
                                                                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID" use="optional"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Function" use="optional"/>
                                                                                                    </xs:extension>
                                                                                                </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                                                                        </xs:element>
                                                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                            <xs:element name="Programs">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                        <xs:element name="Program" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                                                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="JobSequence" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Home" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Sheet" use="required"/>
                                                                                                    </xs:extension>
                                                                                                </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                                                                        </xs:element>
                                                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                            <xs:element name="Tools">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:sequence>
                                                                                        <xs:element name="Tool" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                                                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Type" use="required"/>
                                                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="required"/>
                                                                                                    </xs:extension>
                                                                                                </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                            </xs:complexType>
                                                                                        </xs:element>
                                                                                    </xs:sequence>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                            <xs:element name="UserNumbers">
                                                                                <xs:complexType>
                                                                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="NumberRequired" use="required"/>
                                                                                        </xs:extension>
                                                                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                                </xs:complexType>
                                                                            </xs:element>
                                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="optional"/>
                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Manufacturer" use="optional"/>
                                                                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="RobotIndex" use="optional"/>
                                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                                </xs:element>
                                                                <xs:element name="TypePlaceholder" minOccurs="0">
                                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                                        <xs:simpleContent>
                                                                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                                                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
                                                                            </xs:extension>
                                                                        </xs:simpleContent>
                                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                                </xs:element>
                                                            </xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID" use="required"/>
                                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="required"/>
                                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="IsRobot" use="required"/>
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="ID" use="optional"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>

                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="ID" use="optional"/>
                                </xs:complexType>

                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ImportDocuments">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="HandshakeDocument" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="required"/>
                                            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="ImportDate" use="required"/>
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="uniqueEMNameParentID">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//EM"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
            <xs:field xpath=".//Station/@ID"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Complete XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PLC Name="PLC">
    <Type>
      <TypeDef ID="1" Name="G05" Description="" />
    </Type>
    <SA ID="01">
      <Station ID="100">
        <EM ID="01" Name="IR01" IsRobot="TRUE">
          <Robot Name="AR01" Manufacturer="FANUC" RobotIndex="1">
            <Jobs>
              <Job ID="1" Description="Handling Step 1" Type="" />
              <Job ID="2" Description="Handling Step 2" Type="" />
              <Job ID="3" Description="Handling Step 3" Type="" />
              <Job ID="4" Description="Handling Step 4" Type="" />
              <Job ID="5" Description="Handling Step 5" Type="" />
              <Job ID="6" Description="Handling Step 6" Type="" />
            </Jobs>
            <Areas>
              <Area ID="1" Description="100TP01" TargetEM_No="" />
              <Area ID="2" Description="100FR02-FX01" TargetEM_No="" />
            </Areas>
            <Userbits>
              <Userbit ID="1" Description="Userbit1: Pick_Action">
                <Reference Area="2" Job="5" />
              </Userbit>
              <Userbit ID="2" Description="Userbit2: Drop_Action">
                <Reference Area="1" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="3" />
                <Reference Area="3" Job="4" />
                <Reference Area="3" Job="6" />
              </Userbit>
              <Userbit ID="30" Description="xx_Mute_Sensors">
                <Reference Area="1" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="3" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="3" />
                <Reference Area="3" Job="4" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="5" />
                <Reference Area="3" Job="6" />
              </Userbit>
              <Userbit ID="31" Description="xx_Type_Transfer">
                <Reference Area="2" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="3" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="3" />
                <Reference Area="3" Job="4" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="5" />
                <Reference Area="3" Job="6" />
              </Userbit>
            </Userbits>
            <FZones />
            <Programs>
              <Program ID="1" JobSequence="1;2;3;4;5;6;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR01_P1" />
              <Program ID="2" JobSequence="2;3;4;5;6;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR01_P1" />
              <Program ID="3" JobSequence="3;4;5;6;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR01_P1" />
              <Program ID="4" JobSequence="4;5;6;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR01_P1" />
              <Program ID="5" JobSequence="5;6;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR01_P1" />
              <Program ID="6" JobSequence="6;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR01_P1" />
            </Programs>
            <Tools>
              <Tool ID="1" Type="spotweld gun" Name="FG01" />
              <Tool ID="2" Type="adhesive gun" Name="FG02" />
            </Tools>
            <UserNumbers NumberRequired="True" />
          </Robot>
          <TypePlaceholder Name="" />
        </EM>
      </Station>
    </SA>
    <SA ID="02">
      <Station ID="100">
        <EM ID="02" Name="IR01" IsRobot="TRUE">
          <Robot Name="AR02" Manufacturer="FANUC" RobotIndex="2">
            <Jobs>
              <Job ID="1" Description="Handling Step 1" Type="" />
              <Job ID="2" Description="Handling Step 2" Type="" />
              <Job ID="3" Description="Handling Step 3" Type="" />
              <Job ID="4" Description="Handling Step 4" Type="" />
              <Job ID="5" Description="Handling Step 5" Type="" />
              <Area/>
            </Jobs>
            <Areas>
              <Area ID="1" Description="100TP02" TargetEM_No="" />
              <Area ID="2" Description="100FR01-FX01" TargetEM_No="" />
              <Area ID="3" Description="100FX01" TargetEM_No="" />
            </Areas>
            <Userbits>
              <Userbit ID="1" Description="Userbit1: Pick_Action">
                <Reference Area="2" Job="4" />
              </Userbit>
              <Userbit ID="2" Description="Userbit2: Drop_Action">
                <Reference Area="1" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="3" />
              </Userbit>
              <Userbit ID="30" Description="xx_Mute_Sensors">
                <Reference Area="2" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="3" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="4" />
                <Reference Area="3" Job="5" />
              </Userbit>
              <Userbit ID="31" Description="xx_Type_Transfer">
                <Reference Area="2" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="1" />
                <Reference Area="1" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="2" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="3" />
                <Reference Area="2" Job="4" />
                <Reference Area="3" Job="5" />
              </Userbit>
            </Userbits>
            <FZones />
            <Programs>
              <Program ID="1" JobSequence="1;2;3;4;5;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR02_P1" />
              <Program ID="2" JobSequence="2;3;4;5;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR02_P1" />
              <Program ID="3" JobSequence="3;4;5;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR02_P1" />
              <Program ID="4" JobSequence="4;5;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR02_P1" />
              <Program ID="5" JobSequence="5;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR02_P1" />
            </Programs>
            <Tools>
              <Tool ID="1" Type="gripper" Name="FG01" />
            </Tools>
            <UserNumbers NumberRequired="True" />
          </Robot>
          <TypePlaceholder Name="Type" />
        </EM>
        <EM ID="03" Name="IR03" IsRobot="TRUE">
          <Robot Name="AR03" Manufacturer="FANUC" RobotIndex="3">
            <Jobs>
              <Job ID="1" Description="Tackweld Step 1" Type="" />
              <Job ID="2" Description="Tackweld Step 2" Type="" />
              <Job ID="3" Description="Tackweld Step 3" Type="" />
              <Job ID="4" Description="Tackweld Step 4" Type="" />
              <Job ID="5" Description="Tackweld Step 5" Type="" />
              <Job ID="6" Description="Tackweld Step 6" Type="" />
              <Job ID="7" Description="Tackweld Step7" Type="" />
            </Jobs>
            <Areas>
              <Area ID="1" Description="100FR01-FX01" TargetEM_No="" />
              <Area ID="2" Description="100FR02-FX01" TargetEM_No="" />
            </Areas>
            <Userbits />
            <FZones />
            <Programs>
              <Program ID="1" JobSequence="1;2;3;4;5;6;7;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR03_P1" />
              <Program ID="2" JobSequence="2;3;4;5;6;7;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR03_P1" />
              <Program ID="3" JobSequence="3;4;5;6;7;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR03_P1" />
              <Program ID="4" JobSequence="4;5;6;7;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR03_P1" />
              <Program ID="5" JobSequence="5;6;7;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR03_P1" />
              <Program ID="6" JobSequence="6;7;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR03_P1" />
              <Program ID="7" JobSequence="7;" Home="1" Sheet="FA01++100+IR03_P1" />
            </Programs>
            <Tools>
              <Tool ID="1" Type="spotweld gun" Name="GW01" />
            </Tools>
            <UserNumbers NumberRequired="False" />
          </Robot>
        </EM>
      </Station>
    </SA>
  </PLC>
  <ImportDocuments>
    <HandshakeDocument Name="DO30011_FA01_Robot_PLC_Handshake_v6" ImportDate="18/04/2024" />
  </ImportDocuments>
</Project>


Please supply an executable repro: a complete schema and source document that demonstrates the problem. (For example, it's critical where in your schema the xs:unique constraint appears). Also: does your C# code pick up other validation errors, or is it only the uniqueness constraint that gives problems?

I've added the complete XML and XSD as an example. Is that what you mean? The unique constraint is the only constraint that is giving a problem.

You can express this with Schematron and XSLT/XPath 2 or later, I think e.g.
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="PLC">
            <assert 
              test="every $station1 in .//Station satisfies
                    every $station2 in .//Station[not($station1 is .) and $station1/@ID = @ID] satisfies 
                    not($station1/EM/@Name = $station2/EM/@Name)">duplicate Names</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>

Or you can use XSD 1.1 with assertions e.g. with a schema like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">
    
    <xs:element name="Project">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PLC" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Type">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="TypeDef">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
                                                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                                                <xs:attribute name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="SA" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="Station">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="EM" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                            <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
                                                            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                                                            <xs:attribute name="IsRobot" type="xs:string"/>
                                                        </xs:complexType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>                                        
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:assert id="no-duplicate-names" 
                            test="every $station1 in .//Station satisfies
                                  every $station2 in .//Station[not($station1 is .) and $station1/@ID = @ID] satisfies 
                                  not($station1/EM/@Name = $station2/EM/@Name)"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>  
    
</xs:schema>

an instance like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project>
    <PLC Name="PLC">
        <Type>
            <TypeDef ID="1" Name="G05" Description="" />
        </Type>
        <SA ID="01">
            <Station ID="100">
                <EM ID="01" Name="IR01" IsRobot="TRUE"></EM>
            </Station>
        </SA>
        <SA ID="02">
            <Station ID="100">
                <EM ID="02" Name="IR04" IsRobot="TRUE"></EM>
                <EM ID="03" Name="IR03" IsRobot="TRUE"></EM>
            </Station>
        </SA>
    </PLC>
</Project>

should be valid while an instance like
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project>
    <PLC Name="PLC">
        <Type>
            <TypeDef ID="1" Name="G05" Description="" />
        </Type>
        <SA ID="01">
            <Station ID="100">
                <EM ID="01" Name="IR01" IsRobot="TRUE"></EM>
            </Station>
        </SA>
        <SA ID="02">
            <Station ID="100">
                <EM ID="02" Name="IR01" IsRobot="TRUE"></EM>
                <EM ID="03" Name="IR03" IsRobot="TRUE"></EM>
            </Station>
        </SA>
    </PLC>
</Project>

is invalid (and e.g. SaxonEE would tell you
Validation error on line 3 column 21 of names-invalid.xml:
  FORG0001: Element PLC does not satisfy assertion every $station1 in .//Station satisfies
  every $station2 in .//Station[not($station1 is .) and $station1/@ID = @ID] satisfies
  not($station1/EM/@Name = $station2/EM/@Name)
  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#sec-cvc-assertion clause 0
  Nodes for which the assertion fails:
  * element(Station) at PLC/SA[1]/Station[1]
  * element(Station) at PLC/SA[2]/Station[1]

)
XSD 1.1 is support by at least two open-source libraries (Apache Xerces Java https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/, Python XMLSchema https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/) and various commercial libraries like SaxonEE or AltovaXML.
A sample .NET 8 console application using the Python library XmlSchema with the PythonNet package is online at https://github.com/martin-honnen/PythonNETXmlSchemaTest1.

Thank you for your answer! I've got some problems placing the xs:assert rule. I get the error: element not supported in this context. I've placed it in the complex of the "PLC" element. Any idea what it could be? I've tried moving it around to different complex types but i cannot get it to work.

@MaartenSchuurmans, I guess the problem is mainly that you assume the assert works with any schema processor, like Microsoft's .NET one. But assertions were introduced in the latest version XSD 1.1 of XSD, that has been years ago, but unfortunately many XSD 1.0 schema processors/validators, like the Microsoft ones, have never been updated to support XSD 1.1. So you would basically need to switch to a different stack, complicated by the fact that Saxon EE for .NET is commercial and that the other (open source) options are in Java or Python so to use from .NET you need IKVM or a Python bridge.

@MaartenSchuurmans, I have added a link to a sample .NET 8 console application that uses the NuGet package pythonnet to perform XSD 1.1 validation with the help of the open source Python XmlSchema library.

I don't know why there's a difference between schema processors, but I do note that in your uniqueness constraint, the field <xs:field xpath=".//Station/@ID"/> is never going to select anything when starting from an EM element, so it's probably not doing what you intended.
I believe that the rule in XSD 1.0 is that when one of the fields selects nothing, the uniqueness constraint is deemed to be satisfied. However, it's the kind of area where schema processors aren't always 100% conformant.
Update
You have now given more information. In particular, you have given an (informal) statement of the constraint you are trying to enforce:

Note that my XML has two Station elements with the attribute ID=100.
These elements both have a child element EM with the attribute name =
IR01. This should not be possible.

I'm not sure whether than can be expressed in XSD 1.0. You seem to be saying it's OK to have two Stations with the same ID, provided that they have non-overlapping sets of values for EM/@name.
The problem is that if you try to express this as a constraint on Station elements, it involves selecting an open-ended number of fields, but if you try to express it as a constraint on EM elements, it involves accessing ../@ID as one of the fields participating in the constraint, and upwards selections are not allowed.
But perhaps I've misunderstood the constraint.

What would be the correct way to do it then? Should i use the selector to go to the station element. Then use the xs:field to find each EM element? Because when i try it like that, it only checks for uniqueness within the same station element, not for all station elements

You've understood the constraint correctly. It is possible to have two station elements with the same ID. So if i understand you correctly, this constraint does not seem to be possible?
